# How do I hide navigation bar in the tab bar's specific view in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

XCode11 beta3, 
MacOS Catalina 10.15 Beta（19A501i）

I want to hide tabBar when push~ Any command will very helpful, Thanks~

[Click me to show gif image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dpJ1.gif)
:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        WhenNavigationViewIsRootView()
    }
}

struct WhenNavigationViewIsRootView : View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TabbedView{
                Rectangle().foregroundColor(.green)
                    .tag(0).tabItem{Text("Page1")}

                VStack {
                    List {
                        ForEach(0...2) { i in
                            NavigationLink(
                                destination: Text("\(i)"),
                                label: {Text("\(i)")})
                        }
                    }
                }.tag(1).tabItem{Text("Page2")}
            }
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've deleted my answer - it really should have been a comment since I wasn't providing a solution to your problem. I was also slightly mistaken about the errors in your question. The problem is in your gifs. The canvas in gif 1 is not the correct canvas for the code displayed in gif 1, and the canvas in gif 2 is not the correct canvas for the code displayed in gif 2. The canvases should be swapped. That's why the description you provided for what was happening seemed backwards to me - because the canvases were backwards. I would suggest you edit your question, so others might be able to help.

Comment: Anyway still thanks ~ 
Because your previous comment is help me to clarify the problem.

Comment: I would like to know the answer to this question myself as I am having the exact same issue

Comment: @Rob I've updated my answer. Let me know if that solves the issue for you or if you have other questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to hide the navigation bar in a `TabbedView`, you have to set `.navigationBarHidden(true)` on the views nested inside `TabbedView`. This isn't enough, however. For whatever reason, SwiftUI requires that you first set the navigation bar title before you can hide the navigation bar.

```swift
NavigationView {
    TabbedView{
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(.green)
            .tag(0)
            .tabItem{
                Text("Page1")
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("")
            .navigationBarHidden(true)

        List(0...2) { i in
            NavigationLink(destination: Text("\(i)")) {
                Text("\(i)")
            }
        }
        .tag(1)
        .tabItem {
            Text("Page2")
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("")
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response and remind, I have fix my description, and change the question as you recommand.

Comment: Seem's need some property like "hidesBottomBarWhenPushed" in SwiftUI

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621863-hidesbottombarwhenpushed

Comment: Thank you for detail explanation and code example :)

Comment: The question is "How do you hide the tab bar?" but thi shows how to hide the navigation bar, which is not an answer to the question.

Comment: @GeneZ.Ragan You’re right. The original question was confusing, and it was hard to understand exactly what the original poster was looking for. My answer seemed to correctly answer the question they were asking at the time I posted it, but they continued to edit the question, so it doesn’t actually answer the question anymore. Since they marked it as the accepted answer, I was never really sure if I should delete it. The real answer is that there isn’t a way to hide the tab bar as far as I can tell.

Comment: Thanks @graycampbell I have searching for many hours but I was unable to hide the nabber. Now with the this .navigationBarTitle("") it working perfectly.