# SwiftUI hide TabBar in subview

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, ios13

I am working with SwiftUI, and I have some issues with the TabBar.
I want to hide the TabBar on a specific subview.

Have tried with

```
UITabBar.appearance().isHidden = true
```

It only works on the direct views in the TabView. But when I place it in a subview it doesn't work.

Have anyone a solution for this?

Thanks.

Comment: In order to see the effect you have to reload the view after `isHidden` property is changed

Comment: pretty sure this is a copy of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57026662/how-do-i-hide-the-tab-bar-in-a-specific-view-in-swiftui

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I hide the tab bar in a specific view in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57026662/how-do-i-hide-the-tab-bar-in-a-specific-view-in-swiftui)

Comment: It is not the Navigation bar I want to hide. But the TabBar in the bottom of the view.

Comment: does anybody know if this is availably natively in iOS 15?

Answer (score 61):

**iOS 16 native way**

`.toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)`

Comment: YES!!!!! FINALLY :D

Comment: We live in spectacular days

Comment: Unfortunately when navigating back it is displaying the tabbar not until the navigation transition has finished. With UIKit the tab bar would be sliding in together with the view

Comment: Hey @heyfrank! Did you find another solution? We need something like `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed`. I don't understand what we don't have this out of the box...

Comment: Nope, best way is to file a detailed bug report at Apple. The code of this answer should be the way to achieve it, so Apple must fix it. Especially since it's a declarative framework.

Comment: I thought with a `TabView` you have to apply that to the whole `TabView`. But even better: You must / can apply this to each tab item individudally, so you have exact control which tab item shows.

Comment: @heyfrank I hope they're fixing this issue very soon. It's pretty annoying, because it's a so important feature if you want to build a chat app or something else where the tabbar is hidden.

Comment: Is there a way to add animation to this? I have my subview slide in, so if I just attach `.toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)` to the `SubView()`, the tab bar disappears instantly and it looks bad. Is it possible to hide the toolbar using a slide down transition?

Comment: If anybody is wondering this answer solves the problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/73601830/5515745. The view is no longer shaking on way back and the tabbar is visible instantly.

Comment: This does not really solve the problem because you are using a TabView inside a NavigationView.  This is not the way how to use both together, and it leads to more issues.

Comment: It's possible to show and hide the tab bar with animation when you make the visibility based on a variable which changes when navigating to another screen `.toolbar(isNavigationStackEmpty ? .visible : .hidden, for: .tabBar)` and you either change this variable with animation or use it as a value for animation modifier.

This trick works for me in some places but doesn't work in others, I hope together we'll figure out how to set this up right 

Answer (score 18):

## iOS 14

Install the Introspect SwiftPM: https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect

```
struct SomeView: View{
    
    @State var uiTabarController: UITabBarController?
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            -your code here-
        }
        
        .navigationBarTitle("Title", displayMode: .inline)
        .introspectTabBarController { (UITabBarController) in
            UITabBarController.tabBar.isHidden = true
            uiTabarController = UITabBarController
        }.onDisappear{
            uiTabarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
        }
    }
}
```

In this code in `uiTabarController`, we are taking the reference of `UITabarController`. When we go back then we enabled the `Tabar` again. So, that's why this is needed.

Comment: try to navigate to the view where the tabbar is hidden -> put the app into the background -> resume the app -> navigate backwards. you should see that your content moved down

Comment: Does it only hides tabbar or also collapses it makeing above viewcontroller expand entire screen?

Comment: looks nice, two bad things; when the tabbar appears again, it appears slowly. 2. we need to put this code in every view... any suggestions to improve this?

Comment: @HrabovskyiOleksandr did you find a solution for that problem?

Comment: @Emre only for iOS 14 with `.fullScreenCover` modifier

Comment: @HrabovskyiOleksandr here is the solution I found without fullScreenCover https://stackoverflow.com/a/71942500/4612406

Comment: It works and  you can hide TabBar on exact screen but like most answers when you going back to parent view the TabBar appears slowly

Comment: TabBar appears transparent after moving back to parent view...

Answer (score 12):

[image]

To hide TabBar when we jumps towards next screen we just have to place `NavigationView` to the right place. Makesure Embed `TabView` inside `NavigationView` so creating unique `Navigationview` for both tabs.

As explained here https://janeshswift.com/ios/swiftui/how-to-hide-tabbar-on-push-with-swiftui/

```
import SwiftUI

struct TabBarView: View {
    
    @State var tabSelection: Int = 0
    @State var tabArray = ["Profile", "Settings"]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TabView(selection: $tabSelection){
                ForEach(0 ..< tabArray.count, id: \.self) { indexValue in
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()){
                        VStack{
                            Text("\(tabArray[indexValue]) tab -- Click to jump next view")
                        }
                    }
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "\(indexValue).circle.fill")
                        Text(tabArray[indexValue])
                    }
                    .tag(indexValue)
                    
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(tabArray[tabSelection])
        }
    }
}
struct DetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Detail View")
            .navigationBarTitle("NavigatedView")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .navigationTitle("helllo")
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain what does "so creating unique NavigationView for both tabs" mean? I'm quite new to SwiftUI and this luckly working solution is very confusing. Why when I wrap my TabView in NavigationView (or in my case NavigationStack) suddenly it disappears when redirecting to a SubView and previously it was always visible?

Comment: This works for me even on iOS 13. No need for any additional coding. Just put the NavigationView and TabView in the right order.

Comment: Man, that was the only thing that worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

## **iOS 15** solution

This solution works well except with view modifier in the SwiftUI.TabView.
Since my TabView is in the struct that conforms `App`, it looks like there still is not any `UITabBar` subview in the connected scenes.

With the code below, you only need to use `showTabBar()` or `hiddenTabBar()` in your SwiftUI.View.

```
extension UIApplication {
    var key: UIWindow? {
        self.connectedScenes
            .map({$0 as? UIWindowScene})
            .compactMap({$0})
            .first?
            .windows
            .filter({$0.isKeyWindow})
            .first
    }
}


extension UIView {
    func allSubviews() -> [UIView] {
        var subs = self.subviews
        for subview in self.subviews {
            let rec = subview.allSubviews()
            subs.append(contentsOf: rec)
        }
        return subs
    }
}
    

struct TabBarModifier {
    static func showTabBar() {
        UIApplication.shared.key?.allSubviews().forEach({ subView in
            if let view = subView as? UITabBar {
                view.isHidden = false
            }
        })
    }
    
    static func hideTabBar() {
        UIApplication.shared.key?.allSubviews().forEach({ subView in
            if let view = subView as? UITabBar {
                view.isHidden = true
            }
        })
    }
}

struct ShowTabBar: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        return content.padding(.zero).onAppear {
            TabBarModifier.showTabBar()
        }
    }
}
struct HiddenTabBar: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        return content.padding(.zero).onAppear {
            TabBarModifier.hideTabBar()
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    
    func showTabBar() -> some View {
        return self.modifier(ShowTabBar())
    }

    func hiddenTabBar() -> some View {
        return self.modifier(HiddenTabBar())
    }
}
```

Comment: While this seems to work initially, if the user pulls and drags on the edge of the to navigate back and then let goes, the tab bar appears to appear.

Comment: Hi @Gabriel, can't understand how to resize view after it will showing? tabbar hides, but his size from bottom still affecting other views... Problem resolves if I move app to inactive state using swipe and come back..

Comment: Thanks for the solution I just used hideTabBar in onAppear for iOS 17.4 and it worked

Answer (score 9):

here's no way to hide TabView so I had to add TabView inside ZStack as this:

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        TabView {
            TabBar1().environmentObject(self.userData)
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "1.square.fill")
                    Text("First")
            }
            TabBar2()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "2.square.fill")
                    Text("Second")
            }
        }

        if self.userData.showFullScreen {
            FullScreen().environmentObject(self.userData)

        }
    }
}
```

UserData:

```
  final class UserData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var showFullScreen = false
}
```

TabBar1:

```
struct TabBar1: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData

    var body: some View {
        Text("TabBar 1")
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
            .background(Color.green)
            .onTapGesture {
                self.userData.showFullScreen.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

FullScreen:

```
struct FullScreen: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData

    var body: some View {
        Text("FullScreen")
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
            .background(Color.red)
            .onTapGesture {
                self.userData.showFullScreen.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

check full code on [Github](https://github.com/fakiho/FullScreenTabView)

there's also some other ways but it depends on the structure of the views

Answer (score 9):

It's working, only changes are need to be called on the main queue

```
struct ShowTabBar: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        return content.padding(.zero).onAppear {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                Tool.showTabBar()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct HiddenTabBar: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        return content.padding(.zero).onAppear {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                Tool.hiddenTabBar()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Traverse the allsubview of the window to hide the UITabBar. You can write it as ViewModifier and use it in SwiftUI or use tools to hide it. This method works for me.

```
    extension UIView {
        
        func allSubviews() -> [UIView] {
            var res = self.subviews
            for subview in self.subviews {
                let riz = subview.allSubviews()
                res.append(contentsOf: riz)
            }
            return res
        }
    }
    
    struct Tool {
        static func showTabBar() {
            UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: { $0.isKeyWindow })?.allSubviews().forEach({ (v) in
                if let view = v as? UITabBar {
                    view.isHidden = false
                }
            })
        }
        
        static func hiddenTabBar() {
            UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: { $0.isKeyWindow })?.allSubviews().forEach({ (v) in
                if let view = v as? UITabBar {
                    view.isHidden = true
                }
            })
        }
    }
    
    struct ShowTabBar: ViewModifier {
        func body(content: Content) -> some View {
            return content.padding(.zero).onAppear {
                Tool.showTabBar()
            }
        }
    }
    struct HiddenTabBar: ViewModifier {
        func body(content: Content) -> some View {
            return content.padding(.zero).onAppear {
                Tool.hiddenTabBar()
            }
        }
    }
    
    extension View {
        func showTabBar() -> some View {
            return self.modifier(ShowTabBar())
        }
        func hiddenTabBar() -> some View {
            return self.modifier(HiddenTabBar())
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's working fine me also but I'm facing some issues above iOS 14.0 like tabbar is reappearing when user focusing the textfield even I hided the tabbar. Is there any idea why it's occuring?

Answer (score 9):

#### iOS 14 Simple Solution

Install the Introspect SwiftPM: https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect

```
var body: some View {
    List {
        -your code here-
    }
    
    .navigationBarTitle("Title", displayMode: .inline)
    .introspectTabBarController { (UITabBarController) in
        UITabBarController.tabBar.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

NOTE: You have to re-enable the TabBar it in the parent view or it will still be hidden.

```
.introspectTabBarController { (UITabBarController) in
            UITabBarController.tabBar.isHidden = false
}
```

Comment: It hides successfully, but I cannot get it to re-enable it when the user navigates back to the parent. I think this is because when the user goes backwards in the navigation the parent view does not get refreshed. How did you solve this issue?

Comment: Works flawless, but do not forget to make your view fullscreen, otherwise you will have a big gap at the bottom of your view

Comment: @Gary Declare a variable to save the tabBar reference and then .onDisappear() of the same view set it back.
```
@State private var tabBar: UITabBar?

.introspectTabBarController { UITabBarController in
    tabBar = UITabBarController.tabBar
    self.tabBar?.isHidden = true
}

.onDisappear() {
    self.tabBar?.isHidden = false
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem as Gary. The Tabbar doesn't appear again. Does somebody have a solution because @xdeleons doesn't work

Comment: Actually not working perfectly: you have to define `isHidden = false` everywhere else;

Comment: @LiangWang have you found a better solution?

Answer (score 9):

### On iOS 16

Use `.toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)`.

For example:

```swift
var body: some View {
    TabView {
        FirstView()
            .tabItem {
                Text("First tab")
            }
            .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)

        SecondView()
            .tabItem {
                Text("Second tab")
            }
            .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
    }
}
```

Note that `.toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)` is applied to each `tabItem`, not to the parent view. YMMV if you have a different structure (like a parent NavigationView etc.)

Answer (score 5):

The basic idea I'm using is to combine ObservableObject and ZStack. I have placed TabView into ZStack with conditional subview presentation.
[It's look like](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qw_i9xYDxSs&feature=youtu.be).
Look through [github repo](https://github.com/nikishovde/HideTabBarInSubview)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 5):

**iOS 16**

Usage of `.toolbar` modifier. Create state property of type `Visibility` and manage its value from the pushed view

First view

```
struct FirstTab: View {
    @State var tabBarVisibility: Visibility = .visible

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: WidgetDetailView(tab: self)) {
                Text("test")
            }   
        }
        .toolbar(tabBarVisibility, for: .tabBar)
    }
}
```

Second view

```
struct WidgetDetailView: View {
    var tab: FirstTab
    
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(Color.red)
            .onAppear {
                tab.tabBarVisibility = .hidden
            }
            .onDisappear {
                tab.tabBarVisibility = .visible
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah nice.  Rather that add a reference to the `FirstTab`, I passed a binding to a property called `tabsVisibility`.  That way the sub view didn't need to know anything about the host view.

Answer (score 3):

Install the Introspect SwiftPM: https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect

in order to use this you need to create a variable of type UITabBar in the view you want the tabbar to be hidden...

```
enter code here

@State private var tabBar: UITabBar?
```

then below the navigationView in the same view you have to add this line:

```
            .introspectTabBarController { UITabBarController in tabBar = UITabBarController.tabBar
                self.tabBar?.isHidden = true } .onDisappear() { self.tabBar?.isHidden = false }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

in general, it's nice to be able to create pages with an w/o tabbar
it looks smooth and your page content doesn't change it's size while hiding tabbar on the page

solution is

- hide tabbar from  the root container
- add custom tabbar modifier
- use this modifier on navViews to show the tabbar for all nav view hierarchy OR use it on the specific pages in the view hierarchy

here is a small sample project how your app could look like with this approach
https://github.com/alexis-ag/swiftui_classic-tabview_show-hide

Comment: This appears to me to be the best approach to the problem. Tested on iOS 14 and 15.

Comment: Dude you are awesome. this is best solution. motivation part of your solution is where I was struggling as I was thinking that at least this should work. SwiftUI sucks.

Comment: note: in ios 16 you are able to control tabbar appearance with specific modifiers
look at this please: https://sarunw.com/posts/swiftui-tabview-color/

Answer (score 1):

It is actually possible to get the underlying UITabbarController for TabView by using this handy little framework :

https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect

This solution uses the MVVM pattern as an example to have programmatic control over the Tabbar visibility, and be able to show, hide, enable, disable form anywhere in the code using NSNotifications

SwiftUI View : Setup the tabview like this

```
struct MainTabView: View {

var viewModel: MainTabViewModel

var body: some View {

    TabView() {

        Text("View1")
        .tabItem {
            Text("View1")
        }

        Text("View2")
        .tabItem {
            Text("View2")
        }

    }

    .introspectTabBarController { tabBarController in
        // customize here the UITabBarViewController if you like
        self.viewModel.tabBarController = tabBarController
    }

}
}
```

Then for the ViewModel

```
final class MainTabViewModel: ObservableObject {

var tabBarController: UITabBarController?

init() {
    startListeningNotifications()
}

func startListeningNotifications() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(showTabbarView), name: "showBottomTabbar", object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(hideTabbarView), name: "hideBottomTabbar", object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(enableTabbarTouch), name: "enableTouchTabbar", object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(disableTabbarTouch), name: "disableTouchTabbar", object: nil)
}

@objc func showTabbarView() {
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
}

@objc func hideTabbarView() {
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
}

@objc func disableTabbarTouch() {
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
}

@objc func enableTabbarTouch() {
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}

deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}


}
```

and finally to control the tabbar, just use these fonctions from wherever you feel like (will be in the viewmodels in the pattern of this example)

```
public func showTabbar() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .showBottomTabbar, object: nil)
    }
}

public func hideTabbar() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .hideBottomTabbar, object: nil)
    }
}

public func enableTouchTabbar() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .enableTouchTabbar, object: nil)
    }
}

public func disableTouchTabbar() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .disableTouchTabbar, object: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Increase the frame size of TabView like this:

```
.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: showTabbar ? UIScreen.main.bounds.height : UIScreen.main.bounds.height + 100.00)
```

Comment: It will work but SwiftUI views layouts from center and it seems to need other value to place it correctly

Answer (score 1):

Not ideal and hacky but the simplest thing to do for me that is working very well was to hide the navigationBar of the outer navigationView and then add another navigationView in each of the TabView's views.  Works well so far:

```
struct LaunchView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TabView {
                ViewA()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("TabA", systemImage: "some.image")
                    }
                ViewB()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("TabB", systemImage: "some.image")
                    }
                ViewC()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("TabC", systemImage: "some.image")
                    }
            }
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
    }
}

struct ViewA: View {
        
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            // Content
            .navigationTitle("Settings")
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}
```

This way you can set the title but also the .toolBarItem's in each separate view.

Comment: I found this the other day and I've been really happy with it. However, up till today I'd only been using iOS 14 simulators. If you use iOS 15, you end up with a bigger space at the top of child views, aka two NavigationViews. You can fix this by removing your child view NavigationViews but you then get the tab bar in child views  I haven't been able to find a workaround so far.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to use https://stackoverflow.com/a/62963499/11844048 solution but the TabBar hide in all views once I landed this view. I have modified it a bit to achieve to hide TabBar in single view.

```
   struct AppInfoView: View {
        @Environment(\.presentationMode) var mode: Binding<PresentationMode>
        var body: some View {
            ZStack{
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .background(Color("homepage_bg")).ignoresSafeArea(.all)
            .onAppear{
                UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: { $0.isKeyWindow })?.allSubviews().forEach({ (v) in
                    if let view = v as? UITabBar {
                        view.isHidden = true
                    }
                })
            }
            .onDisAppear(...) //it works too. But seeing TabBar shown bit delay when naviagting back. So below the customizable back button.
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            .navigationBarItems(leading: Button(action : {
                self.mode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: { $0.isKeyWindow })?.allSubviews().forEach({ (v) in
                    if let view = v as? UITabBar {
                        view.isHidden = false
                    }
                })
            }){
                Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
            })
}

extension UIView {

        func allSubviews() -> [UIView] {
            var res = self.subviews
            for subview in self.subviews {
                let riz = subview.allSubviews()
                res.append(contentsOf: riz)
            }
            return res
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Most answers here deal with this requirement in one of two ways:

- import a framework to locate the UITabBarController
- modify the view hierarchy (ZStack, NavigationView, ...)

The first one is a clean approach: it locates the underlying element that enables the desired action. However, **it may be overkill for a single use case**.

The second approach **involves some tradeoffs and could be generally considered a smell**, since it introduces hierarchy changes for the sake of working around the lack of access to the required element.

Instead, we could follow a **clean, simple approach** by creating a protocol extension like so:

```
import UIKit

protocol TabBarAppearanceDelegate {
    func toggleVisibility()
    func hideTabBar()
    func showTabBar()
    // add more methods to control appearance as needed
}

extension TabBarAppearanceDelegate {
    private var tabBarController: UITabBarController? {
        // this is where we access the underlying element, no need to import a framework for a one-liner
        UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: { $0.isKeyWindow })?.rootViewController?.children.first as? UITabBarController
    }
    
    func toggleVisibility() {
        tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden.toggle()
    }
    
    func hideTabBar() {
        tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
    }
    
    func showTabBar() {
        tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

Then we can make any object conform to this protocol, and inject it as dependency in the views as needed. This will depend on your architecture but it could go like follows.

This is where you'd keep app-wide state, an `ObservableObject` (you could designate a different one, if preferred):

```
import Foundation

class StateController: ObservableObject {
    // you would typically manage app-wide state here
}

// this is where we adopt the needed behaviour
extension StateController: TabBarAppearanceDelegate {}
```

We can now inject the object as a view dependency:

```
@main
struct TabBarVisibilityApp: App {
    private let stateController = StateController()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            TabView {
                NavigationView {
                    SampleView(tabBarAppearanceDelegate: stateController)
                }
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Home", systemImage: "house")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is how you would use it (valid for in any view that requires the behaviour):

```
import SwiftUI

struct SampleView: View {
    let tabBarAppearanceDelegate: TabBarAppearanceDelegate
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Button(action: {
                tabBarAppearanceDelegate.toggleVisibility()
            } ) {
                Text("Toggle tab bar visibility")
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

This approach is **simple, testable, and requires no extra dependencies**... until Apple provides a direct way to control tab bar visibility with a SwiftUI API.

Comment: Great approach, but it just blacks out the tabBar. Any idea how SwiftUI will expand to use the space?

Comment: Um, I don't quite follow @NicolasDegen. Will it be something related to `scrollEdgeAppearance`? There is some new behaviour in iOS15 that may affect the tab bar. See here for instance: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69467581/1811775

Comment: This does work for me, it's almost perfect, I used a `@StateObject` in my app file and `@EnvironmentObject` where you have sample view. I also used onAppear and onDisappear, for show / hide. However onDisappear was quite slow to show the tab bar again :(

Answer (score 0):

It is possible!
Basically your task is to extract UITabBar somehow and then hide it programatically.

Below is the code which emulates tab bar hiding on push behaviour.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ForEach(titles, id: \.self) { title in
                NavigationView {
                    view(fromTitle: title)
                }
                .tabItem {
                    Text(title)
                    Image(systemName: "photo")
                }
                .tag(title)
            }
        }
    }

    private let titles = ["one", "two"]

    @ViewBuilder
    private func view(fromTitle title: String) -> some View {
        if title == "one" {
            RegularView(title: title)
                .navigationTitle(title)
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        } else {
            HideOnPushView(title: title)
                .navigationTitle(title)
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
    }
}

struct RegularView: View {
    let title: String

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            Text(title)
            NavigationLink("Regular push") {
                Text("1111111")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct HideOnPushView: View {
    let title: String

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            Text(title)
            NavigationLink("Hide on push") {
                Text("222222")
                    .onAppear {
                        tabBar?.hide()
                    }
            }
        }
            .background(
                TabBarExtractor(tabBar: $tabBar)
            )
            .onAppear {
                tabBar?.show()
            }
    }

    @State private var tabBar: UITabBar?
}
```

TabBar extractor code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TabBarExtractor: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var tabBar: UITabBar?

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType, context: Context) {}

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> some UIViewController {
        let controller = ViewController()
        controller.onTabBarAppearance = {
            tabBar = $0
        }
        return controller
    }
}

private extension TabBarExtractor {
    class ViewController: UIViewController {
        var onTabBarAppearance: ((UITabBar) -> Void)?

        override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillAppear(animated)

            if let tabBar = self.tabBarController?.tabBar {
                onTabBarAppearance?(tabBar)
            } else {
                print("Could not locate TabBar! Try change extractor place in views hierarchy.")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

TabBar category:

```
import UIKit

extension UITabBar {
    func toggleVisibility() {
        if isHidden {
            show()
        } else {
            hide()
        }
    }

    func show() {
        guard isHidden else { return }

        let visibleY = frame.origin.y
        let hiddenY = visibleY + frame.height
        frame.origin.y = hiddenY
        isHidden = false

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) { [weak self] in
            self?.frame.origin.y = visibleY
        }
    }

    func hide() {
        guard !isHidden else { return }

        let visibleY = frame.origin.y
        let hiddenY = visibleY + frame.height

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) { [weak self] in
            self?.frame.origin.y = hiddenY
        } completion: { [weak self] completed in
            guard completed else { return }

            self?.isHidden = true
            self?.frame.origin.y = visibleY
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Browsed through all the answers, there are always deficiencies

I chose custom, which has the following benefits:

1.Support iOS15

2.TabBarView does not nest NavigationView

3.Do not break the logic of TabBarView

4.Requires only a small amount of code and is fully customizable

copy my code to run

**core code**

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct HideTabBarViewApp: App {
    
    init() {
        UITabBar.appearance().isHidden = true
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var selection = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection) {
            TabItemView(selection: $selection, tabBarType: .home) {
                PageView(pageType: .home)
            }
            .tag(0)
            
            TabItemView(selection: $selection, tabBarType: .contact) {
                PageView(pageType: .contact)
            }
            .tag(1)
            
            TabItemView(selection: $selection, tabBarType: .search) {
                PageView(pageType: .search)
            }
            .tag(2)
            
            TabItemView(selection: $selection, tabBarType: .user) {
                PageView(pageType: .user)
            }
            .tag(3)
        }
    }
}
```

**Custom TabItemView**

```swift
struct TabItemView<Content: View>: View {
    
    @Binding var selection: Int
    @State var tabBarType: TabBarType
    @ViewBuilder let content: () -> Content
    
    var imageArray = ["rectangle.roundedtop", "message", "magnifyingglass", "person"]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                content()
            }
            .frame(maxWidth:.infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
                tabBarView
            }
        }
    }
    
    var tabBarView: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(Array(imageArray.enumerated()), id: \.element) { index, image in
                Button {
                    withAnimation {
                        selection = index
                    }
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: image)
                        .font(.title2)
                        .foregroundColor(index == tabBarType.rawValue ? .blue  : .gray)
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
        }
        .frame(height: 40, alignment: .top)
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .padding(.top)
        .background(.bar)
    }
}
```

**some business logic code**

```swift
struct PageView: View {

    @State var pageType: PageType
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach((1...20), id: \.self) {
                    NavigationLink {
                        SettingView()
                    } label: {
                        Text("Go to setting")
                    }
                    .id($0)
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle(pageType.rawValue)
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .frame(maxWidth:.infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}

struct SettingView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Setting Page")
            .font(.title)
            .navigationTitle("Setting")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

enum PageType: String {
    case home = "Home"
    case contact = "Contact"
    case search = "Search"
    case user = "User"
}

enum TabBarType: Int {
    case home = 0
    case contact = 1
    case search = 2
    case user = 3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a Modifier utility that hides the `TabBar` for `iOS 16` or older versions [I successfully tested it on `iOS 16` and `iOS 15`].

Create `TabBarModifier` swift file and add the following:

```swift
import SwiftUI

/// adapted from [TabBarModifier](https://github.com/artemisak/DiaCompanion_iOS/blob/360258e07d4a3e3521a1ec6893f29f175d67034f/dia/Extensions/extensions.swift#L86-L87)
extension View {
    func showTabBar() -> some View {
        if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
            return toolbar(.visible, for: .tabBar)
        } else {
            return modifier(ShowTabBar())
        }
    }
    
    func hideTabBar() -> some View {
        if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
            return toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
        } else {
            return modifier(HideTabBar())
        }
    }
}

private struct HideTabBar: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        return content.padding(.zero).onAppear {
            TabBarModifier.hideTabBar()
        }
    }
}

private struct ShowTabBar: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        return content.padding(.zero).onAppear {
            TabBarModifier.showTabBar()
        }
    }
}

private struct TabBarModifier {
    static func showTabBar() {
        guard let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: { $0.isKeyWindow }) else {
            return
        }
        
        keyWindow.allSubviews().forEach { subView in
            if let tabBar = subView as? UITabBar {
                tabBar.isHidden = false
            }
        }
    }
    
    static func hideTabBar() {
        guard let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: { $0.isKeyWindow }) else {
            return
        }
        
        keyWindow.allSubviews().forEach { subView in
            if let tabBar = subView as? UITabBar {
                tabBar.isHidden = true
            }
        }
    }
}

private extension UIView {
    func allSubviews() -> [UIView] {
        var subviews = [UIView]()
        subviews.append(contentsOf: self.subviews)
        subviews.forEach { subview in
            subviews.append(contentsOf: subview.allSubviews())
        }
        return subviews
    }
}
```

Then use it like any modifier. example:

```swift
struct Example: View {
    var body: some View {
        StatsView()
            .hideTabBar()
    }
}
```

let me know if there is a way to cleanup or improve this :)

Answer (score -1):

There is my solution:

- designed to solve tab bar visibility with `NavigationView` nested in `TabView`
- no mess with UIKit
- no need to store anything in you view (like @Environment or @State etc)

```swift
//
// Created by Maxime Ashurov on 27/09/2023.
//

import SwiftUI

private class TabBarVisibilityObject: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = TabBarVisibilityObject()
    private init() {}

    @Published var visibility: Visibility = .visible
}

private struct TabBarVisibilityModifier: ViewModifier {
    let visibility: Visibility
    @StateObject private var visibilityObject = TabBarVisibilityObject.shared
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
        .onAppear {
            visibilityObject.visibility = visibility
        }
        .toolbar(visibilityObject.visibility, for: .tabBar)
    }
}

public extension View {
    func hidesTabBar() -> some View {
        self.modifier(TabBarVisibilityModifier(visibility: .hidden))
    }
    func showsTabBar() -> some View {
        self.modifier(TabBarVisibilityModifier(visibility: .visible))
    }
}
```