# Hide statusbar in swift ui, when .statusbar(hidden: true) does not work or react

Tags: swiftui, ios13, statusbar

I have an app that loads a tabbar with a view as initial screen, RecipeList(). Inside of RecipeList I call another view to show a recipe full screen. In RecipeList file I have code to show or hide the status bar checking if the recipe detail fullscreen view is loaded or not. It works perfectly if I preview it in xcode, BUT when I preview the code below, which is my Home() view file, and what I want to load as initial screen due to tabbar need, THEN the code inside of RecipeList to show or hide statusbar doesnt work anymore, and status bar is always on.

If i try to hide the statusbar in the code below, it works, but then is always off, something i dont want. Only wanna hide it for the fullscreen view.

I actually used this Introspect package from Github to hide the tabbar when the child view is loaded full screen, and i made it work!

[SwiftUI hide TabBar in subview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58444689/swiftui-hide-tabbar-in-subview/62563861#62563861)

https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect

Actually, I wonder if anyone has used Introspect to hide the statusbar like the tabbar. I tried to use it, but I am a rockie, I only know a bit of SwiftUI, no Swift, no view controller experience, nothing.

But I have a totally functional app with only this issue, and I am super frustrated not to have the skills to know why the tabbar view is forcing a persistent status bar.

Any help, please?

```
var body: some View {

    ZStack {
                
        Color("background2")
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                
        TabView {
        
            RecipeList().tabItem {
                    
                Image(systemName: "book.fill")
                    .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .bold))
                    
                Text("Galería")
                
            }

            PostList(section: sectionData[0]).tabItem {
                    
                Image(systemName: "list.bullet")
                    .font(.system(size: 22, weight: .bold))
                    
                Text("Listado")

            }
                
        }
        .accentColor(Color("accent"))
        .introspectTabBarController { tabBarController in

            // customize here the UITabBarViewController if you like
            self.viewModel.tabBarController = tabBarController
   
        }
                
    }
   
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample project on how you got it to work please!?

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you using the @EnvironmentObject wrapper which basically allows you to use an object as global state. You can find fair amount of tutorials explaining how to do that and inject it in your initial view so that this object is accessible in the whole view hierarchy.

Once you have that global state set up, you can hide your status bar conditionally like this:

```
MyOutterWrapper {
    Text("Some text")
}
.statusBar(hidden: myGlobalState.statusBarHidden)
```

If you are using NavigationView note that hiding the status bar works best if you set it up there (also assuming navigation view is your first view that appears).

Now all you got to do is inside your view set the variable to true when entering full screen and set it back to false when exiting. Hope that helps!

EDIT: Forgot to mention that hiding status bar as of June 26, 2020 only works if it's set on the initial view. You cannot change it later and that's the reason we set up this variable in order to go back and change the value dynamically.

Comment: I tried your example, and I did this: class HideTheBar: ObservableObject {@Published var hide = false}

In my Home() main view:   @EnvironmentObject var bar: HideTheBar and   .statusBar(hidden: bar.hide) 

and in the loaded view  .onAppear{self.bar.hide = true} .onDisappear{self.bar.hide = false}

the status bar does what i want, to disappear then, BUT when that happens the full interface is like refreshed, so all the position of the UI elements is lost, and it breaks the UI, as it is a view that is loaded with GeometryReader data, etc. It does a refresh that resets and breaks all :(

Comment: @IkerOrtizdeArri yes that is intended to happen. If you are using GeomtryReader you should expect that something will break. And yes if you conditionally change something on the UI it does a refresh :)

Comment: But the Introspect package I use to hide the tabbar when fullscreen childview doesn't refresh at all the screen, it does just that, hide one element without fanfarre. Do you see another way I can hide the statusbar without the refresh?