# How to hide UIKit Tabbar in UIViewControllerRepresentable in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, storyboard, uikit

I am trying to accessing the Storyboard View Controller in SwiftUI by using `UIViewControllerRepresentable`. I want to hide the UIKit Tabbar which we applied on `ItineraryViewController` by using the `planDetailViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true` But that solution not working.

````
  let eventGroup : EventGroup?
  func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
    guard let planDetailViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(identifier: "ItineraryViewController") as? ItineraryViewController else {
      fatalError("ViewController not implemented in storyboard")
    }
    planDetailViewController.userActionMode = .viewOnly
    planDetailViewController.itinerary = eventGroup!.event
    planDetailViewController.shouldDisableCalendarVC = true
    planDetailViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
    return planDetailViewController
  }
  func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType, context: Context) {
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Your UIViewControllerRepresentable won't get pushed into a UINavigationController like in UIKit so hidesBottomBarWhenPushed will not be respected.

The best way to do this is using Introspect like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64182729/3393964

Comment: Sir I am using IOS 13.6 and Introspect is in IOS 14. So what i can do in IOS 13.6

Comment: @OnlineDeveloper Introspect is not iOS 14