# How to hide navigation bar correctly and elegantly in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

It does not effectively hide the navigation bar

```
.navigationBarHidden(viewModel.tabNavigationHidden)
.navigationBarTitle(viewModel.tabNavigationTitle, displayMode: .inline)
```

Comment: It doesn't work very well when switching pages

Answer (score 0):

To hide the navigation bar, use

view

```
  .navigationBarTitle("")
    .navigationBarHidden(true)
```

This has to be applied on every NavigationLink destination as well. For example:

```
NavigationLink(
    destination: OtherView()
        .navigationBarTitle("")
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
) {
    Text("Click me")
}
```

Comment: I set it in the body of OtherView but it does not work

Comment: @TemaTian [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57026662/how-do-i-hide-navigation-bar-in-the-tab-bars-specific-view-in-swiftui#:~:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20hide,can%20hide%20the%20navigation%20bar.] Check this